# How to get child table values in frappe.route_options along with Parent table values

Tags: erpnext, frappe

In sales order , I have a button for creating Allotment which is a custom doctype. Using frappe.set_route I am able to get parent table values but not sure how to get child table values along with it. Kindly help, thanks!

```js
frappe.ui.form.on('Sales Order', 'refresh', function(frm) {
  frm.add_custom_button(
    __('Make Allotment'),
    function() {
      frappe.route_options = {
        customer: cur_frm.doc.customer,
        sales_order: cur_frm.doc.name,
        delivery_date: cur_frm.doc.delivery_date,
        set_warehouse: cur_frm.doc.set_warehouse
      };
      frappe.set_route('Form', 'Allotment', 'New Allotment');
    },
    __('Make Allotment')
  );
});
```

Comment: you could use `locals[cdt][cdn]` directly to get the child table values

Comment: where should i exactly use locals[cdt][cdn]

Comment: you could use locals to get the child table values, pass them through route_options and use them accordingly on your new Form